# jQuery on with selector doesn't work on container

Tags: jquery

Example: i got a container #abc, in there is a second block #def
i need to connect some events that happen inside the def container.
in this case an click on an input inside the legend of a fieldset.

But some events might replace the body of the second #def block, in the example done by the button.

now the #def block is replaced, the events that are connected to #abc should still trigger, but they doesn't. I think they should

What i thought should work was this:

```
$('#abc').on('click', 'fieldset > legend > input', function() {
    console.log("B");
});
```

But that doesn't seems to work anymore?

Even this doesn't work:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", '#abc fieldset > legend > input', function() {
    console.log("O");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qz3jeod/

The API doku says it should have worked: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Edit:

enable of the fieldset isn't the solution for me, because that is what the checkbox should do

Comment: Firstly, for me in Chrome `B` appears. It's `C` that has the issue as the `fieldset` has the `disabled` attribute set on it, so it will not raise any events.

Answer (score 0):

Remove disabled attribute and it will work:

```
<fieldset disabled="disabled">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qz3jeod/1/

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem:
the input inside the legend is for disable & enable of the fieldset

Comment: Then, I'm afraid you will have to change your code so that the checkbox is outside the field set, and maybe use some css in order to show the checkbox over the title of your fieldset. Click event won't be triggered by disabled elements.